# How to check if a date is between other dates?

Tags: php

I get two dates from GET

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

I then convert them into dates:

```
$start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-yy', $start);
$end  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-yy', $end);
```

If I var_dump them I get

```
object(DateTime)#8260 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-01 18:05:42.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } 
object(DateTime)#7967 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-05 18:05:42.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

I then loop my posts and in a custom field I have a date, which is a string, therefore I convert it into a date:

```
foreach($posts as $post) { 
   $myDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-yy', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80'));
```

And if I vur_dump that I get

```
object(DateTime)#8457 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2000-03-20 18:07:28.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

Then I finally do:

```
if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) {
....
```

But I don't get the correct results as if that conditions isn't working at all

Comment: what would you expect as correct result? (right the result would be that the condition is _not_ met)

Comment: it means it should filters all posts within those dates only but it is like ignoring that condition

Comment: please give a concrete example of what is happening now with what input

Comment: Apropos of nothing, if you are using PHP < 5.2 all date comparisons where considered equal

Comment: You date, in the sample, is 2000-03-20, that's not going to evaluate as being between $start and $end which are both in 2019

Comment: Can you replicate this same problem via php fiddle or something? Cause there are a whole lot of things which could go wrong on your env.

Comment: @crunchy I have taken one post, that shouldn't be shown indeed, because isn't in between those dates. Thats why it is not working and I am asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare seconds from Unix epoch start.

```
if ( ($start->format('U') <= $myDate->format('U')) 
    && ( $myDate->format('U') <= $end->format('U'))) {
    // date is between start and end
}
```

Comment: i get zero results if I use that

Comment: if I do var_dump(usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80')); I get string(9) "20-3-2000"

Comment: For 20-3-2000 corect format for createFromFormat is "j-n-Y" not "d-m-yy". Notice the capital Y (not to be confused with y)

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
if ( ( $myDate->getTimestamp() >= $start->getTimestamp()) && ( $myDate->getTimestamp() <= $end->getTimestamp()) )
```

Comment: this break its, and gives me zero results

Comment: if I do var_dump(usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80')); I get string(9) "20-3-2000"